# Problem with group by clause and aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on this question: For each stock exchange, display the symbol of the stock with the highest total trade volume. Show the stock exchange name, stock symbol and total trade volume. Sort the output by the name of the stock exchange and stock symbol.

[Here is the ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZOVx.jpg)

Here is my query and output:

```
SELECT 
    se.name AS "stock exchange name",
    sl.stock_symbol AS "stock symbol",
    SUM(t.shares) AS "highest total trade volume"
FROM stock_exchange se
    JOIN trade t
        ON se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
    JOIN company c
        ON t.stock_id = c.stock_id
    JOIN stock_listing sl
        ON se.stock_ex_id = sl.stock_ex_id and sl.stock_id = c.stock_id
GROUP BY sl.stock_symbol,se.name
HAVING SUM(t.shares) =(
    SELECT 
        MAX(SUM(t.shares))
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            SUM(shares) over(partition by sx.stock_ex_id)
        FROM stock_exchange sx
            JOIN trade tr
               ON tr.stock_ex_id = sx.stock_ex_id
            JOIN company co
                ON co.stock_id = tr.stock_id
    )
)
ORDER BY se.name, sl.stock_symbol;



   Stock exchange name                 stock symbol      highest total trade volumn
   1 Euronext Paris                       BNP              5000
   2 Euronext Paris                       EDF:EN PARIS     78600
   3 London Stock Exchange                BA               126400
   4 NASDAQ Stock Exchange                TESO             164100
   5 New York Stock Exchange              GOOG             132300
   6 New York Stock Exchange              NYT              111900
   7 New York Stock Exchange              TM               50300
   8 Tokyo Stock Exchange                 TYO:6201         5300
```

row 1,6 and 7 are not the highest trade volume by that stock exchange and somehow still displayed in the output. I notice when I don't put sl.stock_symbol in group by function then it prints the exact rows expected. However I need to display this stock symbol column so how to I work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use a window function to get the top stock(s) per stock exchange. For instance:

```
select se.name, sl.stock_symbol, t.total
from stock_exchange se
left join
(
  select stock_ex_id, stock_id, sum(shares) as total
  from trade
  group by stock_ex_id, stock_id
  order by rank() over (partition by stock_ex_id order by sum(shares) desc)
  fetch first rows with ties
) t using (stock_ex_id)
left join stock_listing sl using (stock_ex_id, stock_id)
order by se.name, sl.stock_symbol;
```

`FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES` is available as of Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without having a data sample is quite difficult to know what you actually want. However, as you said **that removing the stock symbol gives you the right values** , perhaps it would be a good idea to remove that part from the group by and recover the field in a new select after the group by. You are not using the field for the having calculation.

**I don't know the volumes you are handling , so performance wise no idea how it would behave**

Example

```
select r.se_name  AS "stock exchange name",
       t.stock_symbol AS "stock symbol",
       r.max_shares as "highest total trade volumn"
from 
(
SELECT 
  se.name,
  se.stock_ex_id
  -- sl.stock_symbol ,
  SUM(t.shares) as max_shares 
FROM stock_exchange se
    JOIN trade t
        ON se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
    JOIN company c
        ON t.stock_id = c.stock_id
    JOIN stock_listing sl
        ON se.stock_ex_id = sl.stock_ex_id and sl.stock_id = c.stock_id
GROUP BY sl.stock_symbol
HAVING SUM(t.shares) =(
    SELECT 
        MAX(SUM(t.shares))
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            SUM(shares) over(partition by sx.stock_ex_id)
        FROM stock_exchange sx
            JOIN trade tr
               ON tr.stock_ex_id = sx.stock_ex_id
            JOIN company co
                ON co.stock_id = tr.stock_id
    )
) 
) r join stock_listing t on r.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id 
ORDER BY r.se_name, t.stock_symbol;
```